# install Xcode in /usr

Tags: xcode, makefile, installation, project

I have a makefile project that I would like to port to Xcode.

I was following the instructions on:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html

The document lists as important to install Xcode in the default "/usr" folder.
But the installer gives no such option.

And it installs the folder Devolopper in the "/" folder.

Is it safe to just move the whole content of "Developper" to "/usr" or should that be done during installation?

If so, how?

Comment: You really *don't* want to do that - just install the BSD tools (how you do this depends on the version of Xcode).

Answer (score 2):

[TFA](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html) says

> If you are using makefiles for compilation, you should install Xcode in the default location (/usr). If you do not, you may have to do extra work to get your scripts to run the compiler, linker, and so on in a nonstandard location.

I'm guessing that the specific path is out of date, but the overall advice of installing Xcode in the standard place is sound. I recommend you use the Xcode installer, which puts make and gcc in the proper places and not worry about /usr in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly do NOT need to move `/Developer` to `/usr`. The docs must be talking about `/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/` folder and others which will be created when Xcode is installed into `/Developer`. You don't need to do anything special for that.

When Xcode tools are installed to the default location (/Developer), the installer creates aliases for developer tools in `/usr` locations automatically. Install and everything will just work: `make`, `gcc`, `ld` and everything else will appear in $PATH. In short, just install and that will be it.

I don't know why the doc says it that way, it must be mistake or misunderstanding.